# xml select next node and change value of that node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I created this xmlfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Contacts xmlns:g="http://something.com">
  <Contact>
    <g:Phone>206-555-0144</g:Phone>
    <g:Name>Patrick Hines</g:Name>
    <g:Address>
      <street>this street</street>
    </g:Address>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I am trying to select the phone node and then try to get the next node. The phone node is unique so that is why i look for this first. How can I change the value of the Name?

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml");
var reader = doc.CreateReader();
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("g", g.NamespaceName);
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Contacts/Contact/g:Phone[text()='206-555-0144']", namespaceManager);

var nd =node.NextNode // does not work

node.Value = "sjfjks";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code does not compile at all. You're missing `;` at the end of problematic line.

And what's probably more important, your assigning `node.NextNode` to `nd` variable (which points to `<name>` element) but your changing `node.Value` instead of `nd`! You should definitely assign more descriptive names to your variables at the first place!

I can make it work with following:

```
var phone = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Contacts/Contact/g:Phone[text()='206-555-0144']", namespaceManager);

// you have to cast NextNode to XElement to allow changing it's value
var name = (XElement)phone.NextNode;

// change name.Value instead of phone.Value!
name.Value = "test";
```

With that `doc` value printed out looks like expected:

```
<Contacts xmlns:g="http://something.com">
  <Contact>
    <g:Phone>206-555-0144</g:Phone>
    <g:Name>test</g:Name>
    <g:Address>
      <street>this street</street>
    </g:Address>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding at first the root node, then if still doesn't work select Phone node without the entire path:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml");
var reader = doc.CreateReader();
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("g", g.NamespaceName);

var root = doc.Root; // set the Root of your document.

var node = root.XPathSelectElement("/Contacts/Contact/g:Phone[text()='206-555-0144']", namespaceManager); 
// if still doen't work try with 
// root.XPathSelectElement("//g:Phone[text()='206-555-0144']", namespaceManager);

var nd =node.NextNode;

node.Value = "sjfjks";
```